# Build Warning: Layout 'XXX-layout' requested in index.md does not exist in Jekyll?

Tags: php, jekyll, documentation, gemspecs, jekyll-theme

I have created a theme of my own using Jekyll named 'north' which I have created by myself.

After creating the theme I got a gem file as 'north-0.1.0.gem' and gemspec file as 'north.gemspec'.

I took both of these file and paste inside a folder named 'north' inside a new project 'docs'.

**north.gemspec**

```
frozen_string_literal: true

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "north"
  spec.version       = "0.1.0"
  spec.authors       = ["kumar.saurabh"]
  spec.email         = ["kumar.saurabh108@abc.com"]

  spec.summary       = "test."
  spec.homepage      = "https://wkrepo.abc.com/saurabh.kumar/uvtheme/tree/2.0"
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").select do |f|
    f.match(%r{^(_(includes|layouts|sass)/|(LICENSE|README)((\.(txt|md|markdown)|$)))}i)
  end

  spec.add_runtime_dependency "jekyll", "~> 3.8"

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.16"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 12.0"
end
```

**_config.yaml**

```
# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
theme: north
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
```

**index.md**

```
---
# Feel free to add content and custom Front Matter to this file.
# To modify the layout, see https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/#overriding-theme-defaults

layout: page-sidebar-layout
---
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem "jekyll", "~> 3.8.5"

# This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.
gem "north", "0.1.0", :path => "north/north-0.1.0.gem_FILES"
```

**Error:**

In terminal:

```
Invalid theme folder: _sass
Invalid theme folder: _includes
            Source: /home/users/kumar.saurabh/www/html/symfony_projects/UVdeskDocs/uvdocs
       Destination: /home/users/kumar.saurabh/www/html/symfony_projects/UVdeskDocs/uvdocs/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
Invalid theme folder: _layouts
Invalid theme folder: assets
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
     Build Warning: Layout 'page-sidebar-layout' requested in _posts/2019-05-09-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'page-sidebar-layout' requested in 404.html does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'page-sidebar-layout' requested in about.md does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'page-sidebar-layout' requested in index.md does not exist.
                    done in 0.179 seconds.
```

**I have one more question:**

When I extracted the .gem file, I got 'data' folder in which _layouts, _includes and _sass folders are present but not the assets folder although I have added 'assets' folder while making .gem file. **why?**

I have followed the following tuturial:
https://www.chrisanthropic.com/blog/2016/creating-gem-based-themes-for-jekyll/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have confused yourselves with the technicalities of a jekyll theme-gem and using a local version.

1. You need not create a theme-gem if you do not plan to share the theme with rest of the Jekyll community.
2. When using `path:` attribute in a Gemfile, you need not generate a `xyz.gem` archive. Just a valid `xyz.gemspec` file is sufficient.

So ideally, your directory structure should simply be:

```
north/
  north.gemspec
  _layouts/
    layoutA.html
    layoutB.html
  _includes/
    lorem.html
    ipsum.html
  _sass/
    foo.scss
    bar.scss
  assets/
    styles.scss
docs/
  Gemfile
  index.md
```

then reference the theme-gem in your Gemfile:

```rb
gem 'north', path: '../north'
```

---

> although I have added 'assets' folder while making .gem file.

The error is in your gemspec:

```rb
f.match(%r{^(_(includes|layouts|sass)/|(LICENSE|README)((\.(txt|md|markdown)|$)))}i)
```

There is no mention of `assets` in the regular-expression above.

You may want to refer the repositories for existing themes like `minima` for proper direction.

Comment: For your point 1, I am not sure about sharing my theme to the community, but right now I want to use my generated theme in my own project locally.

I am going to work on your suggestions but thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Hi ashmaroli, I have edited the changes which you have suggested, results are still the same.

Comment: If you still see `Invalid theme folder: _layouts` output in your terminal, then there's something wrong with your theme or the overall setup. If possible, commit everything in current state to a Git repository and push it to GitHub or similar. Then, post the link to your repository here.